# How do you remove directory qualifiers to simplify pathname using the Win32 API?

Tags: c++, winapi, pathname

If you have a path like "C:\foo\.\bar\.." is there an easy way using the Win32 API to remove the directory qualifiers in order to simplify it to "C:\foo" ?

---

Update: It seems to be a more complicated issue. On this simple example of "C:\foo\.\bar\..", it works with both PathCanonicalize() and GetFullPathName() to get "C:\foo" as a result.

However, the path I'm passing has a symbolic link.  So let's say I'm passing in "C:\NaNa\Boo\Bin\.." and "C:\NaNa" is a link to "D:\Apple".  Then I get "C:\NaNa\Boo\Bin\.." back ratener than "C:\NaNa\Boo"

I would assume the functions work with just the strings but there seems to be a difference when using the symbolic link :-(

---

Update #2: It appears I had a line break character (0x0d) in the string that was passed in and this kept the function from working properly!

Comment: I want to apologize to the person who posted GetFullPathName() as an answer when I commented that didn't work (and they pulled their response).  It actually does work with a correctly formatted string.  At least I only commented rather than downvoting but I still feel an apology is warranted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at shlwapi's [`PathCanonicalize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: For some reason, on my machine (Windows 7), PathCanonicalize() is not removing the trailing ".." - curious because the docs imply it should.

Comment: Odd, works for me on xp, the `buffer_5[]`example @ msdn shows trailing .. being stripped

Comment: Hmm it works for "c:\foo\.\bar\.." -- it just doesn't seem to work for my real longer directory name.

Comment: FWIW, GetFullPathName() works for the "c:\foo\.\bar\.." example too.  For my realworld example, I am using a pathname with a symbolic link in it though.

Comment: The problem turned out to be a bad character in the input string.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: 2022 update: [PathCchCanonicalizeEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchcanonicalizeex) performs a few extra tricks and, used properly, can prevent buffer overruns.