# How to expand a path with \..\ in it

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, path

I have this path :

```
c:\dev\myapp\dirA\..\dirB\myfile.txt
```

how to expand it to :

```
c:\dev\myapp\dirB\myfile.txt
```

Is their any Delphi functions to do this or any winapi function ?

Comment: `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus` normalize path (but convert it to nt form) here question - for what you need this and how want use

Comment: @RbMm i need it because i want to calculate the relative path from c:\dev\myapp\dirA\..\dirB\myfile.txt to c:\dev\myapp\dirB\ that will be simply myfile.txt

Comment: use `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus` for normalize path. remove \..\ \.\ convert / to \ etc

Comment: @RbMm: Is that an **undocumented** Win32 function?

Comment: `PathCchCanonicalize`, or open the file then use `GetFinalPathNameByHandle`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - yes, undocumented. buf this not mean "volatile"

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand It's not just undocumented, it's also not part of the Win32 API.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`SysUtils.ExpandFileName()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.ExpandFileName) function.

```pascal
ExpandFileName('c:\dev\myapp\dirA\..\dirB\myfile.txt');
```

Result:

```
c:\dev\myapp\dirB\myfile.txt
```

Comment: On Windows, `ExpandFileName()` simply calls the Win32 [`GetFullPathName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfullpathnamew) function to handle all of the normalizing. On other platforms, `ExpandFileName()` actually parses the string and does all the normalizing manually.

Comment: [FPCs `ExpandFileName()`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/expandfilename.html) also parses manually, even resolving `...` and `~`. WinAPI wise see [How do you remove directory qualifiers to simplify pathname using the Win32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6599458/4299358), including comments.